# How to re-use a function?

Tags: jquery

I found some code online to to create simple tabs. It works for every (single) instance of a class.
But what if I have 2 different classes and I need it to do the same for both classes?

I am currently duplicating the function. I know, it beats the purpose of constructing a function. Hence the rookie question: How do I re-use the function's code for more than one class.

Thanks!

```
$('.class1').each(function(){
    // code for making tabs work
    // 
});


 $('.class2').each(function(){
    // code for making tabs work
    //
});
```

Comment: Uh... you put it inside a function? `function foo() { ... }` `$("whatever").each(foo)`. Note that your specific example can also be covered simply with `$(".class1, .class2").each(...)`.

Comment: Oops... not an event handler here. But it actually doesn't make a difference. You don't seem to be very familiar with functions, so I suggest to read a tutorial about them (or three): http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions, http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html

Comment: Or you could use a common class... Let's call it `class3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a function that makes your tabs work elsewhere, such that:

```
function makeTabsWork()
{
    // code for making tabs work
}
```

And then assign that function to the individual classes, like so:

```
$('.class1').each(makeTabsWork);

$('.class2').each(makeTabsWork);
```

A more efficient way to do the above, however, is to:

```
$('.class1, .class2').each(makeTabsWork);
```

However, since you do have two different instances of a class you wish to activate via JavaScript, you could simply assign a common attribute, such as:

```
<div class="class1" rel="nav">
```

and

```
<div class="class2" rel="nav">
```

And then only call the function once like so:

```
$('div[rel=nav]').each(makeTabsWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in the beginning of your javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function foo() {
    }
</script>
```

And later you can call that like:

```
$(".class1").each(foo);
```

This is just one of *MANY* approaches though. I would strongly suggest reading more about basic Javascript syntax to find the other ways to solve your issue!

One tutorial that may help [is here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/functions-declarations-and-expressions). If anyone else has more suggestions for tutorials feel free to edit my answer or suggest those in comments!

**Various Approaches**

```
// define a global function
function globalFoo() { };

// Define a global function as a variable:
var globalFooVar = function () { };

// or in run:
$(function () {
   // define your function inside of run (scoped definition)
   function scopedFoo() { };

   // or a scoped variable
   var scopedFooVar = function () { };


   // but no matter how you define it you basically use it the same way:
   $("selector").each(globalFoo);
   $("selector").each(globalFooVar);
   $("selector").each(scopedFoo);
   $("selector").each(scopedFooVar);
});
```

Comment: Thanks drew_w, Appreciate your help and time.